# Passing correlationID's across requests in .net core 5.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am wanting to create a correlation-id to help analyze logs, but I am wanting to generate a single correlation-id per user "session". I.e. one single correlation id from the start to the end of the application (regardless of the operations performed on the web mvc). I was reading up on how to do this using a [middleware](https://ankitvijay.net/2020/11/24/passing-correlation-id-across-requests/) in .net. I attempted to implement this in my project, however when I start the application and perform certain operations (homescreen -> 2nd page view -> 3rd page view -> final page view) it will create a new correlation-id for each view. **Is there a way to generate one single correlation-id that will be for all the operations performed (home view, 2nd page view, 3rd page view, and final page view)?**

`Startup.cs`:

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {

            app.UseMiddleware<CorrelationIdMiddleware>();
            
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors(x => x
               .AllowAnyMethod()
               .AllowAnyHeader()
               .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true) // allow any origin
               .AllowCredentials()); // allow credentials

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

`CorrelationIdContext.cs`:

```
    public class CorrelationIdContext
    {
        private static readonly AsyncLocal<string> _correlationId = new AsyncLocal<string>();

        public static void SetCorrelationId(string correlationId)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(correlationId))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("Correlation Id cannot be null or empty", nameof(correlationId));
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_correlationId.Value))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Correlation Id is already set for the context");
            }

            _correlationId.Value = correlationId;
        }

        public static string GetCorrelationId()
        {
            return _correlationId.Value;
        }
    }
```

`CorrelationIdMiddleware.cs`:

```
    public class CorrelationIdMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public CorrelationIdMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("correlation-id", out var correlationIds);

        var correlationId = correlationIds.FirstOrDefault() ?? Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        CorrelationIdContext.SetCorrelationId(correlationId);

        // Serilog
        using (LogContext.PushProperty("correlation-id", correlationId))
        {
            await _next.Invoke(context);
        }
    }
    }
```

and in my controllers I just have a simple `logger` i.e.`_logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, "First page...");`

**I noticed when debugging in the `CorrelationIdMiddleware.cs` file, when it hits the line:
`var correlationId = correlationIds.FirstOrDefault() ?? Guid.NewGuid().ToString();` it will create a new correlationID even though one already exists. Is there a way to generate one single correlationId for an entire user session (start to end of application)**?

`context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("correlation-id", out var correlationIds);` value after the first `correlationId` is created:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try replacing `Guid.NewGuid().ToString()` with some constant value such as `"mycorrelationid"`

Comment: Can you use the authentication token? Or issue a correlation I'd at the time of authentication. Still keep the request/view correlation tracking as well, but retain the _session_ token as part of the authentication middleware.

Comment: As in "var const myCorrelationId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();`?  Wouldn't that be the same though? @Chetan

Comment: I just want to stick with correlationID at the moment... @ChrisSchaller

Comment: Guid.NewGuid().ToString() generates a new guid all the time. If you want the same value all the time then you should not use it

Comment: I suspect the `correlation-id` header isn't being sent. I'd expect you want to return the correlation id in a response header, and then forward that to future requests from your UI.

Comment: Well I want it to create a new Guid at the start but not to create one if theres an id that already exists.. @Chetan

Comment: Sorry, it is. I just did not include that in the post forgot about posting that section @StephenCleary I have it as `services.AddHttpClient<ServiceApiClient>()....` where it is calling a client class that gets a method from another class

Comment: What you are asking for is a _session_ based token. That is why I suggest you work this into your _authentication_ process because the authentication lifetime in a web application is very similar to the session lifetime. Depending on what your authentication process is, you might already have such a key available. If you are using token based authentication, the authentication token might be a good candidate.

Comment: `it will create a new correlationID even though one already exists` - wait, are you claiming the `??` operator doesn't work? The probability of finding a compiler bug is extremely small.

Comment: I think that this is currently working as expected. What you need is to manage it via session so that you can lookup correlation id from the session and not from request header. If its not available in session, you generate new id and store it and pass it on in request/response header. If you simply try to inspect incoming request header, unless caller is passing it on subsequent calls, you will never get that same correlation id populated in subsequent calls.

Comment: I see now, I will look into token based authentication. Thank you @ChrisSchaller

Comment: @StephenCleary Yes, but I was wanting it not to create a new `correlationId` if there was already one created at the first time of the application was ran. So when the application starts, it will generate a new `correlationId` and as the user navigates through the web application (page 1 through page 4) it will use the same `correlationId` for all of the logs for each page and when the application closes then that `correlationId` is not used again. So that way I can pull up all the logs with that single `correlationId`

Comment: @MarkCo: Yes, I understand what you are trying to do. In your question you say that one "already exists", and it's not clear what this means. Is `correlationIds.FirstOrDefault()` null or not? If it's not null, then it won't be creating a new one. If it's null, then what's the value of the `correlation-id` header?

Comment: @StephenCleary I just checked when I started the application it created a correlationId then when I went to the second page, it was showing that `correlationIds.FirstOrDefault()` was null. The value of `correlation-id` header you are talking about the line above `correlationId` correct? There are alot of things it contains but it looks like it is throwing an exception in the "Form" I just noticed this. Under `Context.Request` is what I was looking at. Please see the original post for the screenshot if it helps you better.

Comment: Is there a specific value I should be looking at under `Context.Request.Headers`?  Update: I made the line `context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("correlation-id", out var correlationIds);` set to a variable and when I debugged it again the value of that variable is "**False**" @StephenCleary

Comment: @MarkCo: Sounds like the frontend request isn't setting that header, then. You can verify this with Fiddler.

Comment: @StephenCleary The frontend request, does that have to do with the `service.AddHttpClient<> ..... client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add()` line in the `startup.cs` file? Sorry I am very new to this

Comment: @MarkCo: No; it's whatever JavaScript is running on your web page. If there's no JavaScript making the request (i.e., it's just a browser request), then you can't pass correlation ids through headers, and you'll need to have a server-side lookup of some kind, e.g., as part of your authentication or in a separate persistent storage.

Comment: I follow now, will take a look at this. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CorrelationId` as presented here and by many middleware implementations is a logging concept traditionally used to track or *correlate* multiple actions that spawned off of a single user action, which would normally be represented as a single HTTP Request.

> What you haven't adequately described is the lifetime of *your* expected *correlationId*. You have specified that the server needs to create it when it does not exist, but in what scenario does it stop existing?

When you want to correlate across multiple requests from the client, then you need to consider one of the following patterns:

1. Client Side manages the lifetime of the token and passes it through as a HTTP Header or otherwise part of the payload that is sent to the server. Server side simply includes this token in the relevant logs.

   - This *passive server* implementation works great for applications that have a back-end distributed over multiple processes, either in the form of web garden, web farm or scaled out cloud infrastructure.
2. Authentication pattern - Client makes a call to obtain the Id or a *token* that can be used as a unique identifier for the current user session. As with option 1, the  client then makes sure that the token is included as a header with all requests to the server.

   - This is identical to token based authenticate patterns, in terms of how the client and the server need to interact
   - You are already using an *Authorization* middleware, there is a high chance that you could simply use the token used in that process as the correlation Id. If you do not want to store the authentication token, then you could modify your authentication process (and response) to simply create the new token and pass it back either in the payload or as a Http Header, then modify the client to receive this header and pass it back with all requests, at the same time that the authentication token is passed back.
   - This still works if you want to create a *Log Out* process or *Get New Id*, I'm assuming here that the token will remain for the duration of all user interactions for this session.
3. Server side session context - When processing requests on the server, use session storage to save and retrieve the current *correlationId*, however I would strongly advise you refer to this as the *SessionId* or *SessionToken*.

   - Refer to [Session and state management in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-5.0) for guidance on how to setup Session State in the first place.
   - Session State and the management of it can get complicated if your web deployment is scaled out, it will work well enough in single instance deployments, but to be production ready you need to ensure that your session is not broken when the web app is deployed over multiple servers.
   - Depending on your chosen implementation, Load balancing may affect your management of the correlation, make sure you set appropriate Session based affinity settings in your network configuration.
   - Session storage is technically designed for storing this sort of metadata, but you may find it simpler to implement either of the first two options, especially for stateless APIs. Depending on your current environment, enabling Session State may introduce additional complexities that might not be worth the effort if you are using Session Storage for a single keyed value.

Comment: Once you have established a _session_ id, you could implement your own middleware to inject this into the `context.Request.Headers` _before_ the _CorrelationId_ middleware is configured, that way your session Id would be used by all the other correlation middleware responses. Be aware that by doing this you lose the ability to track _per-request_ operations. I strongly advise recording _both_ the Request and Session tokens in logs.